# Yii2 REST API Pagination getLinks

Tags: rest, api, yii2

Here is my Code

```
$provider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $model->getReservations($start_time, $end_time),
        'pagination' => [
             'defaultPageSize' => 2 ,
             'pageSize' => 2,
             'pageSizeLimit' => [1, 2],
         ],
    ]);
return $links = $provider->getLinks();
```

Its give me this error

```
  Calling unknown method: yii\\data\\ActiveDataProvider::getLinks()
```

How i get links of gpagination

Answer (score 0):

First you have to get `Pagination` object, by `getPagination()` method. Then, object `Pagination` have method `getLinks()`, so:

```
return $links = $provider->pagination->links;
```

OR

```
return $links = $provider->getPagination()->getLinks();
```

Comment: its return self link   ?page=1 in each equest

Comment: Maybe you have only 1 page? `getLinks()` returns a whole set of links for navigating to the first, last, next and previous pages, so if there's only one page - there will be one link.

Comment: i have 12 records and set paglimit= 2 in the above code? Am i missing somethig

Comment: Try to remove this `pageSizeLimit` from config.